# How can I restore a corrupted level.dat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While I was playing Minecraft, my computer (running Ubuntu) crashed and my game I was playing got corrupted. I've managed to trace the problem to the level.dat and the level.dat_old files. All the code in these files have been erased. Is there a way that I can get back the old code and thus restore my saved game?

Comment: Do you have a backup system running?  If not install one.  Crashplan is nice.

Comment: @Zoredache I just started using Git for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUl1_SzIN8A)
video should help you, It has saved my world too, so I know that it works. If this doesn't help, try [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ckjQYTystg&feature=related) video. (the second link's video has low volume, so if you don't hear anything, be sure to turn it up)

Comment: These videos weren't able to help me since I was running Ubuntu, but I believe they are helpful to other users. Luckily, I found an earlier backup and was able to recover the files myself.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I didn't help, but good job getting your save back.

Answer (score 0):

If the previous two videos don't help you, this one may:

(older video, done for minecraft 1.8, but it's worth a shot.)

In Ubuntu the 'saves' directory is under in `~/.minecraft.` You will need to "show hidden files & folders" to see directories beginning with the period.